# Display height live during resize

Tags: jquery, user-interface, height, live, resizable

I'm trying to display the current height of a div inside that div and it should **update during resize**.

*Jquery UI*

```
$(function() {
    $( ".event" ).resizable({
        grid: 10,
        minWidth: 250,
        maxWidth: 250,
        minHeight: 25
    });
});
    $(function() {
        $( "#calendar" ).sortable();
        $( "#calendar" ).disableSelection();
    });
```

*HTML*

```
<ul id="calendar">
    <li class="event event1"><div id="height1"></div></li>
    <li class="event event2"><div id="height2"></div></li>
</ul>
```

I've tried several things, but to no avail. For example: I've tried using setInterval() but I'm guessing I wasn't using it right.

Can somebody help me out?

**Edit**
Adding the following code to the resizable param didn't help.

```
resize:function(){$('#height1').html($('#calendar').height())}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PaulvdDool/TDD2r/1/

Comment: "I've tried several things" So, what have you tried?

Comment: You can use resize event in your resizable params. See http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#event-resize

Comment: My problem is fixed in [this][1] post.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16769380/displaying-height-disables-jquery-ui-resizable

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its what you are looking for:

```
$( ".event" ).resizable({
        grid: 10,
        minWidth: 250,
        maxWidth: 250,
        minHeight: 25,
        resize:function(){$('#height1').html($('#calendar').height())}
    });
```