# Displaying height disables jquery ui resizable

Tags: height, jquery-ui-resizable

I'm trying to create my own calendar (sort of) by using jQuery UI. I've added `resizable` and `sortable` to my list items and it all works perfect. The next was to display time inside the list items that update when the list items get resized. I wanted to start by displaying the height inside the list items, but doing that disables the `resizable` function.

Like so:
http://jsfiddle.net/PaulvdDool/9PXNc/

Displaying the height outside the list doesn't affect the `resizable` event.
Like so:
http://jsfiddle.net/PaulvdDool/gBANx/1/

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
function getHeight(event) {
    var height = $('#'+event).height();
    $('#'+event+' > p').html(height);
}
```

why you are using document.getElementById().innerHTML when you are jquery ready?
The trick is to apply the new html only to the "p"  tag.

I think if you would like to use

```
$('#'+event).html(height);
```

you need another

```
$( ".event" ).resizable({
    grid: 10,
    minWidth: 250,
    maxWidth: 250,
    minHeight: 25,
});
```

inside your getHeight() Method.